# Aplicar/arrastrar formula hasta última celda vacía

Tags: excel, vba, visual, basic

Lo que necesito es aplicar una formula hasta que haya una celda en blanco/vacía en la columna A.

De momento tengo este código

```
    Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""'000""&MID(RC[-1],1,13)&""000',"""
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B1500")
    Range("B1:B1500").Select
End Sub
```

De que manera tendría que modificar el rango para que el resultado se vea reflejado en la columna B?, conforme a la condición de última celda no vacía en A.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba del siguiente modo:

```
Dim UltimaFila As Long

UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=""'000""&MID(RC[-1],1,13)&""000',"""
Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & UltimaFila)
```

Comentas.